# Coding using time from system(computer)

Tags: plotting, coding-style

Please help me to solve this problem below.

I want to run this coding based on the time given by the system.

Given,

A = ( {
    {E^(I [Beta]1 + I [Beta]3) Cos[[Beta]2t], 
     E^(I [Beta]1 - I [Beta]3) Sin[[Beta]2t]},
    {-E^(-I [Beta]1 + I [Beta]3) Sin[[Beta]2t], 
     E^(-I [Beta]1 - I [Beta]3) Cos[[Beta]2t]}
   } ) /. {[Beta]1 -> 0, [Beta]3 -> 0}
[Beta]2 = Pi;
For[i = 1, i < 11, i++; t++, t = t + TimeUsed[]; Print[A]].

My problem are:
1. I cannot run this coding since I only want β2 influence by time. I want to look the changes of β2 only on time(For example start with t=0s until t=10s).
2. It is true that I used command TimeUsed[] for the time?(I want the time come from the computer).
3. How can I plot the graph from this command TimeUsed[]. I can't make the graph.

Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: A = {{Exp[I* β1 + I* β3] Cos[β2* t], Exp[I* β1 - I* β3] Sin[β2* t]}, {-Exp[-I* β1 + I* β3] Sin[β2* t], Exp[-I* β1 - I* β3] Cos[β2* t]}}; β1 = 0; β2 = Pi; β3 = 0; t = 0;
tu = Table[ t++; t = t + TimeUsed[]; Print[A]; t, {i, 1, 10}] and then ListPlot[tu] but you need to explain more clearly what you mean by "only β2 dependent on time"

Comment: Tq Bill, what I mean by 'only β2 dependent on time' is β2 is varies with time.  For example, 1st case, β2=Pi. 2nd case, β2=2Pi and in both cases, the value of β1 and β3 remain constant. that mean the value β1 and β3 not varies with time.

Comment: I did the coding suggest by u but why the value of identity, I cannot be evaluate? i get the output as: {{-0.8053078857111251 + 0.*I, 0.5928568201610549 + 0.*I}, 
  {-0.5928568201610549 + 0.*I, -0.8053078857111251 + 0.*I}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose I know what you mean.
If you actually want `β2 t` changed while `β2` keeps the constant `Pi`, I guess the following two codes can solve your problem:

```
β1 = 0.;
β2 = Pi;
β3 = 0.;
A={{Exp[I β1 + I β3] Cos[β2 t], Exp[I β1 - I β3] Sin[β2 t]}, {-Exp[-I β1 + I β3] Sin[β2 t], Exp[-I β1 - I β3] Cos[β2 t]}};
```

1. Using [`Animate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html) (or [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)) while setting the setting bar's running speed the same as your computer time's running speed:

   ```
   Animate[Evaluate@MatrixForm@Chop@A, {t, 0, 1}, DefaultDuration -> 1]
   ```
2. Using Dynamic:

   ```
   Dynamic[With[{t = FractionalPart@SessionTime[]}, Evaluate@Chop@A], UpdateInterval -> .1]
   ```
3. I suppose you will need a plot of `A` as a function of `t`, so the following code will solve this problem:

   ```
   Grid[MapIndexed[Plot[#, {t, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "Value at " <> ToString /@ #2}] &, A, {2}]]
   ```

I will further update this post if you can make clearer what you want to do.

Comment: Simply change the DefaultDuration will do the job. In the second solution, use FractionalPart[SessionTime[]/t0]

Comment: Tqvm Wjx for replying. Sorry, this solution is given by you? , It is mean DefaultDuration will run the coding? In second solution why add /t0 at the Session time

Comment: Thank you Wjx. I mention wrong person. I have question;1. do the coding and run it. but the value of Identity cannot be valued. For example, I do the Dynamic and get the result as: Dynamic[With[{t = FractionalPart[SessionTime[]]}, Evaluate[MatrixForm[A]]], ImageSizeCache -> {261., {10., 17.}}, UpdateInterval -> 0.1]. 2. 
I also wonder about the t interval; In 1(using animate), the Default Duration is increased by 1. it is mean by 1 second? How can I fix the duration? For example, I want to fix from t=0s until t=10s.

Comment: I suppose that's my solution...... DefaultDuration measures the time the dynamic will run for a time by default. /10 means that the time it costs to change fractional part from 0 to 1 will increase to 10 times the original.

Comment: I'm very sorry again Wjx, I mention wrong person for the solution. I read the wrong name.

Comment: No need for apologize~ I'll be glad as long as it solves your problem

Comment: I have question;1. I do the coding and run it. but the value of Identity cannot be valued. For example, I do the Dynamic and get the result as: Dynamic[With[{t = FractionalPart[SessionTime[]]}, Evaluate[MatrixForm[A]]], ImageSizeCache -> {261., {10., 17.}}, UpdateInterval -> 0.1]. 2. the time here mean increase by second? 3. How can I get the exact value for each time from this command?